# express & mongoose - Cannot call method 'get' of undefined - using res.json()

Tags: node.js, express, callback, mongoose, bind

and thanks to be there.

**Issue :**
I'm making a tiny mongoose "middleware" to handle a mongoose error :

```
// callback function called at each mongoDB response
var handleDbRes = function(callback) {
    return function (err, entries) {
        if (err) {
            err.status = 500;
            return next(err);
        }

        return callback(entries)  // that line throw the exception
    }
};
```

And so I'm using it into an api endpoint, e.g. :

```
someRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
    models.article.find(handleDbRes(res.json))
})
```

With that code, I encounter an error :

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined

I followed the exception and looked at res.json() declaration, when debugging, I figured out :

```
var app = this.app;
var *** = app.get('***') // that line throw the exception
```

I guess that app is not defined cause app doesn't exists in "this".

Please can you help me to solve this problem ? I think that the reason is simple but I don't get it...

Thanks you for listening ;)

**EDIT :** I tried to `res.json.bind(res)` and it worked, as I thought, but that's really awful to bind this way for most api endpoint and I guess there is another way to do that kind of functionality without that.

**EDIT :** Thanks to Mscdex advices, I modified my code this way :

```
.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
            models.article.find(handleDbRes(res.json.bind(res), next))

...
...
// callback function called at each mongoDB response
var handleDbRes = function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
    return function (err, entries) {
        if (err) {
            err.status = 500;
            return errorCallback(err);
        }

        return successCallback(entries)
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass `res.json`, the context for the `json()` function is lost (it no longer knows what `this` is because it is not bound). So here are a few possible solutions:

Use a bound version of the function so that `this` inside `json()` will always evaluate correctly:

```
someRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
  models.article.find(handleDbRes(res.json.bind(res)))
})
```

Or use a wrapper function instead:

```
someRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
  function respondJSON(val) {
    res.json(val);
  }
  models.article.find(handleDbRes(respondJSON))
})
```

Or just pass in `res` and call `res.json()` inside `handleDbRes()`:

```
someRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
  models.article.find(handleDbRes(res))
})

// callback function called at each mongoDB response
var handleDbRes = function(res) {
  return function(err, entries) {
    if (err) {
      err.status = 500;
      return next(err);
    }

    res.json(entries);
  }
};
```

The other problem is that `handleDbRes()` doesn't have access to `next`, so you need to also pass that function in for when you run into an error.

Comment: Thanks for your detail answer,
I edited my post about a solution for this problem. ;)